# CryptoJS and PHP SHA256

Tags: javascript, php, sha, crypt

I would like to get Both [CryptoJS's SHA256](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-2)  and php's Crypt SHA256 output to match.

PHP crypt has a salt and a number of rounds. E.g. for 5000 rounds and salt of "usesomesillystringforsalt" it would be;

`$hash = crypt('Clear Text String', '$5$rounds=5000$usesomesillystringforsalt$');`

I hope im not blind, but i cant find how to reproduce this behaviour in crypto-js. Its syntax doesn't seem to allow for rounds or salt.

Is it possible or should i just resort to using the basic [PHP hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) instead of crypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CryptoJS API doesn't provide a way to specify a salt or the number of rounds for SHA256. You could add a salt manually if necessary, and specifying rounds doesn't make sense since "plain" SHA256 always uses a fixed number of rounds (64).

The number of rounds in PHP's `crypt()` actually defines how often the SHA256 algorithm is applied consecutively, in order to increase the complexity of brute force attacks. The [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt_sha256.c) comments on this as follows: *"Repeatedly run the collected hash value through SHA256 to burn CPU cycles"*.

As you can see in the source code ([here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt.c) and [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt_sha256.c)), `crypt()` is actually a key derivation function that only makes use of SHA256 to generate cryptographically secure, salted hashes. So it also doesn't simply append the given salt to the key, instead it's a more elaborate process.

**Therefore, it is not possible to get the same results with the algorithms provided by CryptoJS.**

`crypt()` is mainly intended for password hashing. So if you need the hashes for another purpose, `hash()` is a good alternative (and of course creates exactly the same results as `CryptoJS.SHA256()`).

However, bear in mind that any cryptography with JavaScript is generally [considered harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/). Hence, you should better use SSL in your application, if possible, and generate the hashes server side. If this is an option, have a look at [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: Perfect Answer, Thank you for the considered and detailed response.